# Swiftui seems not to work correctly with Cocoapods and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods, swiftui

I'm trying to create an iOS App using SwiftUI. My data is stored within a Google Firebase realtime database. I fetch my data to an ObservableObject so that the UI can be loaded dynamically, if data get's added or removed.
But for some reason I always getting the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" for a Text().

I've already tried to remove the if statements and the Text() but then I'm getting errors in other places. E.g. I also have to write

```swift
HStack{ ... }.padding(.leading, CGFloat(20))
```

If I do not cast 20 to a CGFloat I'm getting the error "'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'".
I know that SwiftUI's error messages aren't that good yet since almost 90% of code failures leads to some ambiguous bla errors. But here I really don't know where these errors are coming from.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct IngredientsTab: View {

    @ObservedObject var ingredientsVM: IngredientViewModel = IngredientViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(ingredientsVM.ingredients, id: \.self){ (ingredient) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: IngredientDetailView(ingredient: ingredient)){
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text(ingredient.name)
                                Spacer()

                                if (Type.NONALC == ingredient.type) {
                                    self.modifier(LabelViewModifier(label: "Non-alcoholic", backgroundColor: .green))
                                } else {
                                    self.modifier(LabelViewModifier(label: "Alcoholic", backgroundColor: .red))
                                }
                            }

                            if (ingredient.pieceGood) {

                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                                    Text("Piece good") // Here I'm getting the error
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .padding(.leading, 20)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it seems to be somehow related to SwiftUI (since it is obviously not working perfectly yet) but also to Cocoapods/ Firebase. In another project I have a similar approach but without using any Pods and it is just working fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cocoapods and/or FireBase. Based on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683764/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-in-xcode-11, it looks like you need to make your ingredient model conform to the `Identifiable` protocol.

Comment: It's difficult to say where the problems is without seeing your IngredientViewModel and LabelViewModifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the issue. 
My Ingredient inherited from Identifiable but also from NSObject. In combination with some faulty constructor and writing

```swift
id: \.self
```

in the ForEach loop led to this strange behavior. I updated my Ingredient to a correct model and removed the above line from the ForEach loop and then it worked.

Thank you for your help!

PS: It is neither related to any Pods nor to Firebase ;)

Comment: For future readers, maybe you could edit your title, question and tags to remove the mentions of CocoaPads and FireBase.